# Joining table to itself and selecting values that don't match

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get all `data` in `id`'s 1-3 that are NOT in `id`'s > 6

I'm using id's for simplicity, but I'm really using timestamps.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO test (id, data) VALUES
(1, 'abc'),
(2, 'def'),
(3, 'ghi'),
(4, 'jkl'),
(5, 'mno'),
(6, 'pqr'),
(7, 'def'),
(8, 'vxw'),
(9, 'yz');
```

One query of the dozens that I've tried.

```
SELECT
  t1.data t1_data,
  t2.data t2_data
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2
  ON t2.id BETWEEN 1 AND 3
    AND t1.id > 6
    AND t1.data <> t2.data
```

So I want to get this result:

```
+----------+
|   data   |
+----------+
|   abc    |
|   ghi    |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.data AS t1_data
FROM test t1
WHERE t1.id BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT *
  FROM test t2 
  WHERE t2.data = t1.data
  AND  t2.id > 6
  );
```

Comment: Haha, you guys came up with eerily similar solutions seconds apart. Crazy. 
Anyway to avoid a subquery? :)

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a (correlated) subquery? By any chance: the ugly `LEFT JOIN WHERE NULL` variant generates the same query plan for this _anti-join_ on every  sane implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure. SQL has always been my weak suit. Everyone always seemed to recommend not using subqueries whenever possible. Well, it works and you have less points than @lc. so you get the checkmark. I still wish I could rewrite this without the subquery. Bah.

Comment: You are comparing a table with itself, so every solution should at least have two "cursors" open to this table and compare the tuples under them _in some way_. (Even in procedural code you'd need two nested loops to accomplish the same result)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a set-within-sets subquery.  I like to approach these using aggregation with the `having` clause, because this is the most general approach.  In your case:

```
select t1.data 
from test t1
group by t.data
having sum(id between 1 and 3) > 0 and
       sum(id > 6) = 0;
```

The conditions in the `having` clause count the number of rows that meet each condition.  The first says that there is at least one row (for a given `data`) with the `id` between 1 and 3.  The second says there are no rows where the `id` is greater than 6.

Comment: I know I tagged mysql, but I try to refrain from using `having`. It looks very elegant, though. Something similar should be possible without the `having`. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.data
FROM test t1
WHERE t1.id BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t2.data = t1.data
    AND t2.id > 6
);
```

I'm using `DISTINCT` here because I assume it's possible for example to have a `data` value with `id=2` and the same `data` value with `id=3`. Remove it as necessary.

Comment: What they say about great minds. I was one second faster, and you are missing a semi colon ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it (probably performance-wise an outer join might be best) but conceptually it is this:

```
SELECT t1.data
  FROM test t1
 WHERE t1.id < 4 
   AND t1.data NOT IN
   (SELECT t2.data
      FROM test t2
     WHERE t2.id > 6)
```

The outer join version would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.data
  FROM test t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN test t2
    ON t1.data = t2.data and t1.id < 4 and t2.id > 6
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```